# Lync server 2013 - OAuthTokenIssuer certificate missing on some of the Front End servers

Tags: lync-2013

Our Lync 2013 Enterprise Edition Front End Pool consists of 3 servers dispersed globally.

We had some issues where users weren't able to join Lync meetings and determined there was a certificate issue on one of the FE's.

That was resolved, but now for some reason the other 2 FE's now show missing OAuthTokenIssuer certificates despite it showing correctly on the 3rd.

**EXAMPLE GOOD SERVER IN THE POOL:**
[image]

**EXAMPLE BAD SERVER IN THE POOL:**
[image]

My understanding from TechNet's article [Assigning a server-to-server authentication certificate to Microsoft Lync Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj205253(v=ocs.15).aspx) states:

> Lync Server's replication service will then automatically create a set of scheduled tasks that will decrypt and deploy the certificate to all your Front End Servers.

So I'm lost as to why the other 2 FE servers aren't showing the OAuth cert anymore, when they were yesterday?  I would restart the FE services but my experience in the past has been that it won't come back up if it doesn't see valid certs.

Is there a way to determine what happened to these certs on the problem FEs?  Potential log files or Powershell commands?  I've tried `Get-CsCertificate -Type OAuthTokenIssuer` to no avail, it reports back an error finding the cert.

Answer (score 1):

**TROUBLESHOOTING**

The following cmdlets were ran on the 3 FE’s:

- `Get-CSManagementStoreReplicationStatus` = Returned expected positive results
- `Invoke-CSManagementStoreReplication` = Ran and waited for replication
- All 3 servers returned true expected results after running `Get-CSManagementStoreReplicationStatus` again
- `Get-CsCertificate –Type OAuthTokenIssuer` = Failed to find cert still

**ANSWER**

In the end however, the simplest answer is usually the best.  Since the Lync Deployment Wizard has a step, STEP 1, that grabs all the replication certs from the Central Store, I went ahead and rand that Step again from the Deployment Wizard on the two problematic Front End servers.  The results showed successful, and when I went and looked again the cert was now there.

Hope that helps someone else.

Comment: Confirmed, re-running the first server deployment step ("Install Local Configuration Store") forces a full download of the up-to-date topology and common certificates.